# Get Seed from wallet on regtest mode

Tags: wallet, regtest, seed

I am doing some tests for an application that signs Bitcoin transactions. I already downloaded the binary files `bitcoin-cli`,`bitcoind` and `bitcoin-wallet` from [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/download). I need to know that the seed of the wallet created by regtest. It is available when the `bitcoin-wallet -regtest info` command returns:

```
Wallet info                                                                             │
===========                                                                             │
Encrypted: no                                                                           │
HD (hd seed available): yes                                                             │
Keypool Size: 1999                                                                      │
Transactions: 103                                                                       │
Address Book: 2
```

I need that seed for run recovery on my app and check if it sign correctly a Bitcoin transaction.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `dumpwallet` command.

While in regtest open the console a/k/a debug window, and type:
`dumpwallet "C:\myfolder\dump.txt"`

This will create a text file with all your keys. At the top you will see your extended master private key. And if you are looking for your HD seed, do a control+f for hdseed, you should find a key with the label `hdseed=1`.

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/sethdseed/